# AWS ECR login with JavaScript SDK --no-include-email flag

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-ecr

I'm trying to run this AWS CLI command:

`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region <my-region>`

But using the JavaScript SDK with `new AWS.ECR(..).getAuthorizationToken` method but I'm getting this error:

`Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://xxxxx.dkr.ecr.<my-region>.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request`

From my understanding, I need to use some flag that is equal to the `--no-include-email` argument in the CLI command but I cannot find how to set it with the JavaScript SDK.

This is my code:

```
const ecr = new AWS.ECR({
    apiVersion: '2015-09-21',
    region: 'my-region'
});

const { authorizationData } = await ecr.getAuthorizationToken().promise();

if(!authorizationData || !authorizationData[0] || !authorizationData[0].authorizationToken){
    throw new Error('AWS getAuthorizationToken failed');
}

const password = authorizationData[0].authorizationToken;
const proxyEndpoint = authorizationData[0].proxyEndpoint;

await childProcessP.spawn('docker', [
    'login',
    '-u', 'AWS',
    '-p', password,
    proxyEndpoint
]);
```

Do anyone know how to do it?

Comment: How did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I'm not, just executed it as a bash command :(

Comment: oh crap... I was trying to upgrade my legacy bash command to something more proper... :/ I guess that's the way to go. Thanks anyway

Comment: We have AWS guys in our offices every week, I'll try to promote some feature request with them :)

Comment: That would be great. I think it should work but I can't get it to work. I'm using aws-sdk to login and get key and then use dockerode to push, but no luck. I have here my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252777/how-to-push-image-with-dockerode-image-not-pushed-but-no-error bashing my head for hours, and ended up with old bash solution... Not sure is even a aws issue at this point

Answer (score 1):

the `AuthorizationToken` contains a base64 encoded `<username>:<password>`

all you need to do is decode and split to get the values you want.

Comment: This should be the answer to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue by using (golang) docker ENGINE libraries.

First I get credential (like you) from the `ecr.GetAuthorizationToken()` 
Then i call  `docker.RegistryLogin()` function.

Here's my code:

```
authToken, err  := ecrSession.GetAuthorizationToken(&ecr.GetAuthorizationTokenInput{})
    if err != nil {
        color.Red(fmt.Sprintf("Getting ECR auth token: %s", err.Error()))
        return err
    }

    auth := types.AuthConfig{
        Username: "AWS",
        Password: *authToken.AuthorizationData[0].AuthorizationToken,
        ServerAddress: *authToken.AuthorizationData[0].ProxyEndpoint,

    }

     authenticatedOK, err := cli.RegistryLogin(ctx, auth)
```

always return to me **400 bad request**.

However by running commands from shell:

`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1`

then copy paste the returning output

`docker login -u AWS -p ... http://account-id.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` it works fine.

Comment: I've noticed also that if I run `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1` the resulting token differs from the one generated at runtime from `ecrSession.GetAuthorizationToken` function.

So I forced  the code to use the token resulting from shell command and the request goes fine. 

I've also tried to run shell command without `--no-include-email` but the token it's still the same (the correct one).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and I found in the documentation the token return in authToken.AuthorizationData[0].AuthorizationToken is a base 64 encoded string.

So if you want to use it to login your docker you have first decoded it.

When decoded you will se the something like: AWS:eyJwYXlsb2FkIjoiZGhtVzc5Sj....

It turns out the token is encoded with the user. Therefore, you have to take out the AWS: and use the remain string.